# When I was using a dll comiled by msvc_2015 in qt's program,my program works ok,but debuging shows segemts error

Tags: c, matlab, qt, dll

firstly, I have to say the dll was translated by MatLab's m file, which was compiled by c compiler using msvc_2015.

The dll was C shared library, which was said that has a common interface.
I don‘t think it's MatLab's error,because my program works.

The qt was compiled by MinGW_64_4.9.3 on my own computer,so i think qt's configuration is OK.

I can’t figure out why my program works OK, but debugging error, once I was using the `fooInitialize()`, there were a lot of segments error when debugging

[image]

```
QLibrary lib("foo.dll");
QMessageBox msg;

if(lib.load())
{
     QMessageBox::information(NULL,"OK","DLL load is OK!");
     Fun mlfFoo=(Fun)lib.resolve("mlfFoo"); //
     Fun2 init=(Fun2)lib.resolve("fooInitialize");//
     Fun2 termi=(Fun3)lib.resolve("fooTerminate");//
    if (mlfFoo) //
    {
         QMessageBox::information(NULL,"OK","Link to Function is OK!");
         init(); //
         double numbrOut,*out;

         double data[]={1};
         mxArray* array_in,*array_out ;
         array_in = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxREAL);//
         memcpy(mxGetPr(array_in),data , sizeof(double));
         array_out=NULL;
         mlfFoo(1, &array_out,array_in);
         out=mxGetPr(array_out);
         numbrOut=out[0];
         mxDestroyArray(array_in); array_in=0;
         mxDestroyArray(array_out); array_out = 0;
         out=0;
         if(numbrOut==10)  QMessageBox::information(NULL,"NO","perfect!!!!");
        termi();
    }
    else
         QMessageBox::information(NULL,"NO","Linke to Function is not OK!!!!");
}
else
    QMessageBox::information(NULL,"NO","DLL is not loaded!");`
```

I got this few minutes ago
"while parsing target library list: not well-formed (invalid token)"
"SuspendThread (tid=0x788) failed. (winerr 2)"
 the dll's header file was made by matlab using msvc , I compared it to the samples in the matlab's document , it is the similar

Comment: Are you sure that init is not NULL ? have you exported your function with __stdcall and have you use extern "C". if not you need to review your dll. You need to import with a header file matching with your exported funtion... can you put an example of exporting

Comment: `Fun2 termi=(Fun3)` maybe error is here?

Comment: ordinal hint RVA      name

       1    0 00001030 fooInitialize
       2    1 00001050 fooInitializeWithHandlers
       3    2 00001120 fooPrintStackTrace
       4    3 000011B0 fooTerminate
       5    4 00001260 mlfFoo
       6    5 000012A0 mlxFoo     this is exported function's name   i think it's ok

Comment: thank you for replying ,i  change it ,it doesn't work